# Unlink text from audio

Tags: animation, keyframes, audio

I'm really new to blender, I actually just started using it today. I'm usually pretty good at using software like this but I underestimated the difficulty of the tutorial I was trying to follow.

Anyways, I hit a problem towards the end of the tutorial and I think it was something to do with rooting light rays to the audio, and I think I linked my text to the audio instead of the light rays I made or something like that because my text seems to be locked and i cant add other keyframes on to it.

Basically what is happening is that the keyframes i made on the text disappeared and now instead of moving with the keyframes my text spazzes/pulses randomly with the bass of the music.

Something i noticed is that the location and rotation positions for the text are already keyed (in green on the right in the screenshot). I want to get rid of this.

Here's the screenshot

[image: Here's a screenshot]

Thanks to anyone who might help me out here
-Tom

Comment: It sounds like you might have somehow baked a sound file to the F-curves of the text's loc and rot channels. See if deleting the animation channels of the text the graph editor lets you add keyframes again.

Comment: yep, worked like a charm, cheers

Answer (score 1):

If you baked a sound file to the text location an rotation channels, then try deleting the affected animation channels in the [graph editor](http://blender.org/manual/animation/editors/graph.html). Then you should be able to insert keyframes again.

[image]